# Redirection after Form Submit

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How to redirect after post request with node and react js? I have added a route in my server.js file. I am trying to use axios and in .then function I am rendering my view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you intentionally creating a CRUD app using React? Do you want this to be a single page app? If you want to redirect to another server route then you shouldn't use axios. Generally axios is used in single page apps, and in that case you would handle the redirect with a client side router like react-router.

Try not to mix the two approaches you will give yourself a headache.

Comment: I have a main layout component and inside that I want to render different components. They include CRUD operations.

Comment: So you are creating a single page application. In that case you would use client side routing. Look into react-router and the `<Redirect />` component.

Comment: Thnanks a lot!!